# Is there a way with Xamarin.Forms to detect the software keyboard in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application with a login screen. I have added code to move the controls out of the way, when one of the Entry fields gets focus. I move the views back down in the Unfocus event handlers. In the simulator I can prevent the software keyboard from popping up. Unfortunately my event handlers still move the view up and down even without the keyboard.

Is there a way to detect the keyboard's appearance in Xamarin.Forms, while in the event handlers on the ContentPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is support for this out of the box and thus I'd go with [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) and implement it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *ContentPage.LayoutChanged* event. 
It works because the keyboard doesn't display over the content page as one would guess, but under it, in the same layer, so it push the page up.